# How to open a non .txt file using notepad, append to the file, and save

Tags: excel, vba, append, notepad

My problem is that I want to open an .iwp file with notepad, append some stuff to it, and save/close. So far I have:
`AppendToFile = Shell("notepad.exe " & iwpFile, vbNormalFocus)`
How do I append to this file?

Comment: Untested, but is `Write #` an option, instead of using `Shell`?

Comment: When I try to use Write # or Print # I get Chinese characters.. The code I'm using is this: `AppendToFile = "C:\Users\James\Desktop\iwpFile.iwp"`
`Open AppendToFile For Append As #1`
`Write #1, "New Contents"`
`Close #1` The original .iwp file reads "Original File Contents" and after running the code I get "Original File Contents敎⁷潃瑮湥獴丢睥䌠湯整瑮≳"